# Javascript replace regex don't work

Tags: javascript, regex

I have problem with regexp for replace html code in string. I had tried online regexp tester with match, but something causes that I canť replace.
${ProductEAN} is what I want replace. Any idea what is wrong?

The string is here:

```
<label for="ProductEAN" id="ProductEAN" class="col-sm-3 control-label">${ProductEAN}</label>
```

Javascript code:

```
let strToReplace = 'ProductEAN';
let reg = new RegExp('/(\$\{'+strToReplace+'\})/','g')
        str.replace(reg,'some text');
```

Comment: Make sure to mark the best answer as accepted if it helped you. That way it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

The `RegExp` constructor doesn't need slashes (`/.../`) around the expression, that is only for regex literals. And when you backslash-escape characters, they are escaped in the string passed to the constructor, but pass unescaped to the actual regex expression. They need to be double-escaped. So, change the line to this:

```
let reg = new RegExp('\\$\\{'+strToReplace+'\\}','g');
```

Comment: This work for me,thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need proper escaping the backslashes

```
reg = new RegExp('\\$\\{' + strToReplace + '\\}', 'g');
```

and an assignment for the replaced string.

```
newString = str.replace(reg,'some text');
```

```js
var element = document.getElementById('ProductEAN'),
    strToReplace = 'ProductEAN',
    reg = new RegExp('\\$\\{' + strToReplace + '\\}', 'g');

element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(reg,'some text');
```

```html
<label for="ProductEAN" id="ProductEAN" class="col-sm-3 control-label">${ProductEAN}</label>
```

Comment: That is not the issue. The string is not actually properly replaced.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var str = '<label for="ProductEAN" id="ProductEAN" class="col-sm-3 control-label">${ProductEAN}</label>';
var strToReplace = 'ProductEAN';
var reg = new RegExp('(\\${'+strToReplace+'})','g')
str.replace(reg,'some text');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
new RegExp('\$\{' + strToReplace + '\}','g')
```

When invoked with RegExp, you don't have to put the /'s in. You also shouldn't need the ()'s.

More info here: http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Also, you can get rid of the let's. They aren't needed.

Comment: Why would you not need the brackets?

Comment: "Also, you can get rid of the let's. They aren't needed." What do you mean? You have no idea of his context here, so he could possibly want the `let`s.

Comment: The let statement declares a block scope local variable, it is needed

Comment: I just tested it and it worked. The braces are there, I didn't remove them. I only removed the () and the /'s.